# Formatting issue

Tags: r, format

I have a dataset.  Here is how it layed out:

```
ID            A         B        C     
Jim           22        54       23
```

What I want to do with it this:

```
ID          Letters   Numbers
Jim          A       22
Jim          B       54
Jim          C       23
```

Can anyone help please?  I'm fairly new in R.
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = 'Letters', values_to = 'Numbers')
```